# Mockito on JDK16 and Mac OS - Could not initialize plugin

Tags: java, mockito, maven-3

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in java.lang.CompoundEnumeration@4158debd
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 

Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.

    
It appears as if your JDK does not supply a working agent attachment mechanism.
    Java               : 16
    JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
    JVM vendor version : 16.0.2+7-67
    JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    JVM version        : 16.0.2+7-67
    JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
    OS name            : Mac OS X
    OS version         : 11.5
    
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not self-attach to current VM using external process
```

Getting the above error on Maven 3.8.1 and JDK16.02 with Mockito 3.7.7, on a fresh setup and cannot figure out why. I have tried every Mockito version from 3.7 all the way to 3.11 to no avail.

These configurations however works on an older setup based on JDK15 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: can you provide a _minimal, reproducible_ example?

Comment: Is there any error related to mockitomaker

Comment: You mean Mockmaker?  That is the first line of the output from above. 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

Comment: Yeah I noticed it after

Answer (score 0):

- Mockito core depends on a library called byte-buddy and this problem is mostly occurred when mockito doesn’t find a matching byte buddy jar version.
- Find out the mockito core version your project is using. In eclipse, you can check in project build path by navigating to
  Right click on project -> Properties -> Java build path -> Libraries tab

[image: Core dependency]

- Search maven repository for that version of mockito core.
- Look at the Compile Dependencies section. Note down the correct dependent version of byte-buddy and include in the project. If the jar is already included with some other version, override the version with this correct version.

[image: Jar version]

Build the application and run the tests again. Your issue related to MockMaker must be solved by now.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that, added those dependencies to my pom.xml and made sure they are in the external libraries in IntelliJ. Still does not work though.

Comment: Tried updating and restarting the project after the change?

Comment: Just tried removing all cache, and restarting the project but no go...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running with an old 1.8 JDK.  As of this writing with the dependencies below, it has to be Java 11.

```
testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.8.2'))
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter')
testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-junit-jupiter', version: '4.2.0'
testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '4.2.0'
testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2')
```